# DBPedia SPARQL, return certain number of relevant page URIs for entity EXCEPT the URIs where the entity belongs to a set of subclasses of Owl:Thing

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

1. **Looking for SPARQL query to do the following:**

For example, I have the word `Apple`. `Apple` may refer to the organization `Apple_Inc` or the `Species` of `Plants` class as per the ontology. `Owl: Thing` has a subclass called `Species`, so I want to return those most relevant/maximum-hit URIs where the keyword `Apple` does not belong to the `Species` subclass. So when you return all the URIs, `http://dbpedia.org/page/Apple` should not be one of them, neither must ANY relevant link that comes under `Species` subclass.

By maximum-hit/most relevant I mean the top returned results that match the query! Like when you access the `PrefixSearch (i.e. Autocomplete)` API, it has the parameter called `MaxHits`.

For example http://lookup.dbpedia.org/api/search/PrefixSearch?QueryClass=&MaxHits=2&QueryString=berl is a link where you want to return the top 2 URIs  that match the `QueryString=berl`.

Like I'm actually really struggling to even explain the work I've done so far because I'm not able to understand the structure and how to formulate a proper query..

with respect to negation in SPARQL, I found a relevant portion of the documentation in the link [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#negation).. But I do not know how and where to proceed from there, and cannot understand why keywords like `?person` are used.. I can understand the `person` is used to selected well.. PEOPLE names, but I would like to know how and where to find these keywords like `?person`, `?name` to represent a specific entity..

```
SELECT ?uri ?label
WHERE {
?uri rdfs:label ?label .
filter(?label="car"@en)
}
```

I would really appreciate if someone could link me the part of the documentation I can clearly read and understand that `?uri` is used to select a URI in the form `www.dbpedia.org'/page/SomeEntity` and what these `?person`, `?name`, `?label` represent.

I'm actually so lost.. I will go up and start eating one elephant at a time. For now, I'll be very grateful if I get an answer to this.

2. If there is anyway you know where I can avoid learning and using SPARQL, that would work too! I know Python well enough, so leveraging an API to pull this information is also fine by me. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51655411/dbpedia-filtering-using-rest-api-get-all-relevant-uri-for-an-entity-that-do-not) was posted by me.

Comment: what's the problem with 1)? it is just an example how to use negation, the sample data is above the query, SPARQL is about triple pattern matching. `?person` is just a variable name bound to particular entities that match the pattern, i.e. the are of type `Person` and which (because of negation) do **not** have a name ( that exists in the knowledge base).

Comment: @AKSW Could you send me a link that has entity-variable name bindings?

Comment: you're trying to implement an autocomplete feature - like hundreds of people before. without a fulltext index, you"re lost in SPARQL as one would have to use REGEX which is expensive as it has to be applied on the whole intermediate resultset of the query. loading the DBpedia dataset into Lucene would give you better performance, but clearly you won't be able to filter on complex graph patterns then. some triple stores do support fulltext features, e.g. Virtuoso has 'bif:contains' as a custom property.

Comment: what do you mean by link? I just referred to the W3C example, and that the variable is just a placeholder for the entities that match the graph pattern of the query. RDF is just a graph, for the example just draw it on a sheet of paper to see this. then also draw the graph of the query. it will make things clearer. in the end you will do subgraph matching - ok, with negation here, i.e. you filter by "absence of subgraphs"

Comment: here is a starting example returning companies having the token "apple" in its English label: `select distinct ?s where {
?s a dbo:Company .
?s rdfs:label ?label .
filter(langmatches(lang(?label), 'en'))
?label bif:contains '"apple"'
} LIMIT 100`

Comment: @AKSW So for my first question, it is not in fact a simple thing to do? and by link, what I mean is, In the DBpedia, if you want a `dbo:birthName` value for an entity belonging to the class `Person`, Use `?name` to refer to  `dbo:birthName`, and `?classname` if you are querying for a particular class.

Comment: `?person` and `?name` are not keywords, they are variables. This is just convinient to name `?person` the variable that matches the subject in triple pattern `?person rdf:type dbo:Person`.

Comment: `select distinct ?s where { ?s a owl:Thing . ?s rdfs:label ?label . filter(langmatches(lang(?label), 'en')) ?label bif:contains '"apple"' . filter not exists {?s rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf* dbo:Species } }`

Comment: @Stanislav Kralin  Can you post yours as answer do I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer posted by @Stanislav-Kravin --

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ?s 
WHERE
  { ?s a owl:Thing .
    ?s rdfs:label ?label . 
      FILTER ( LANGMATCHES ( LANG ( ?label ), 'en' ) ) 
    ?label bif:contains '"apple"' . 
      FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?s rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf* dbo:Species } 
  }
```